# Can't connect to server (timed out if winsock.dll error 10060) when run blat command to send mail

Tags: cmd, command, mail-server, blat, wsastartup

I am using [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) that is command line tool for sending the mail from command.

First I run the install command to store the mail server which create the entry in registry like that.........

[image]

First I was set the SMTP server to **smtp.mail.yahoo.com** but the error was same.

After that I execute

```
blat C:\temp.txt  -to abcdef@gmail.com -superdebug
```

After that this error I got.......

```
C:\blat310\full>blat C:\temp.txt  -to abcdef@gmail.com -superdebug
Blat v3.1.0 (build : Feb  2 2013 11:00:32)
32-bit Windows, Full, Unicode

Checking option -to
superDebug: init_winsock(), WSAStartup() returned 0 (NO_ERROR)
superDebug: Hostname <smtp.mail.apac.gm0.yahoodns.net> resolved to ip address 10
6.10.167.87
superDebug: Official hostname is smtp.mail.apac.gm0.yahoodns.net
superDebug: Attempting to connect to ip address 106.10.167.87
superDebug: ::connect() returned error 10060, retry count remaining is 1
superDebug: ::connect() returned error 10060, retry count remaining is 0
superDebug: Connection returned error 10060
Error: Can't connect to server (timed out if winsock.dll error 10060)
superDebug: ::say_hello() failed to connect, retry count remaining is 1
superDebug: init_winsock(), WSAStartup() returned 0 (NO_ERROR)
superDebug: Hostname <smtp.mail.apac.gm0.yahoodns.net> resolved to ip address 10
6.10.167.87
superDebug: Official hostname is smtp.mail.apac.gm0.yahoodns.net
superDebug: Attempting to connect to ip address 106.10.167.87
superDebug: ::connect() returned error 10060, retry count remaining is 1
superDebug: ::connect() returned error 10060, retry count remaining is 0
superDebug: Connection returned error 10060
Error: Can't connect to server (timed out if winsock.dll error 10060)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 10060 means that your connection times out, which is because there's nothing listening on port 995 on either `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` or `smtp.mail.apac.gm0.yahoodns.net`. Why do you try to connect to that port anyway? It's used for POP3 over SSL (i.e. mail retrieval), not for SMTP (mail submission).

Try either port 25 or (more likely) port 587. The latter is the default port for message submission (see [RFC 4409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4409) for details).

Answer (score 0):

Your 10060 timeout error is most likely being caused by your mail server not listening to the
Blat default SMTP port # 25.

Many ISP mail servers have switched to SSL encryption for authenication. This switch means using SMTP port # 465. HOWEVER, Blat currently doesnot support SSL.

You will either have to:

1. ask your ISP mailserver to open non-SSL communication, or
2. get an SSL wrapper for Blat( like Stunnel ), or
3. find another command line mailer program that does support SSL.